# How to select all data which was modified by a procedure and store it in an other table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an event calling a procedure.

My event code:

```
CREATE EVENT `apelare_stergere` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 HOUR_MINUTE STARTS
'2019-07-07 15:57:00.000000' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO call stergere_din_rezervari();
```

My procedure called by the above event:

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM rezervari WHERE data_rezervarii < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;  
UPDATE carti SET stoc=stoc+1 WHERE rezervari.idCarte=carti.idCarte;
END
```

I also have a table called `deleted_by_event` and would like to save into it all rows from `rezervari` table what were modified by the procedure.

How can I select all data from `rezervari` table (reservations) which was modified by the procedure? I want to update a field in a third table also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before delete,  insert to a ReservationDelete table? Add a column for the carti ID affected

Then to answer your second question, join to the deleted table?

(If other events need to also delete, then add a DeleteSource column to track the source. )